# Como montar o HTML de um "select" via PHP, usando dados vindos do DB

Tags: php, html5, html-select, mysqli

Estou com problemas para montar corretamente um `<select>` dentro do PHP, com dados retornados pelo `mysqli`.

Tentei desta forma:

```
<?php
   $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "senha","bancodedados" ) or die (mysql_error());
   $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM pv_tipo_info_questionario");
   while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) {
     echo "<select><option name=\"ativo\" value=";
     echo $reg["cod_tipo_info"];
     echo "\"\>";
     echo "<select><option name=\"ativo\" value=";
     echo $reg["tipo_info_questionario"];
     echo "\"\>";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

As respostas existentes já endereçam o problema de forma eficaz, vou deixar a minha sugestão que visa contemplar a optimização do `script` bem como controlar mais eficazmente o resultado do mesmo:

```php
<?php
// iniciar a variável que vai conter o HTML
$outputHtml = '';

// preparar uma mensagem de erro para o utilizador
$erro = '<p>Sem resultados provenientes da Base de Dados!</p>';

// consultar a base de dados
$resultados = $con->query("SELECT * FROM pv_tipo_info_questionario");

// verificar se foram devolvidos resultados
if ($resultados && $resultados->num_rows === 0) { 
    $outputHtml = $erro;
}
else {

    $optionsHtml = '';

    // temos resultados, processar cada um
    while ($row = $results->fetch_array()) {

      // acrescentar à variável que contém o HTML os dados deste registo
      $optionsHtml.= '
      <option value="'.$row["cod_tipo_info"].'">
        '.$row["tipo_info_questionario"].'
      </option>';
    }

    // verificar se temos dados para completar a SELECT
    if (!empty($optionsHtml)) {
      $outputHtml = '
      <select name="ativo">
        '.$optionsHtml.'
      </select>';
    }
    else {
      $outputHtml = $erro;
    }
}

echo $outputHtml;
?>
```

Desta forma não só estás a preparar a caixa de selecção conforme a dificuldade expressa na pergunta, mas estás também a garantir que se alguma coisa correr mal, o utilizador não vai ver uma página vazia ou HTML incompleto levando a uma quebra do *layout*.

Comment: O select trouxe as informações do banco.
E para colocar de forma que funcione na pagina e habilite o botão ao selecionar uma opção?
Pode mesclar o seu código com o meu?
Obrigado.

Comment: @fabricio_wm Não sei qual o restante do teu código para ajudar nesse sentido. De qualquer forma esta tua pergunta trata da questão de construir a  `<select>` assunto que pelo que dizes está agora resolvido. Sugiro que abras uma pergunta nova a questionar sobre como controlar um botão mediante a escolha feita numa `<select>`!

Answer (score 6):

Seu problema é bem simples fabricio, o select deve ser uma tag com os options dentro desta forma:

```
<select name="exemplo">
 <option>Exemplo 1</option>
 <option>Exemplo 2</option>
 <option>Exemplo 3</option>
</select>
```

Seu código está gerando um select por loop no while, mude para:

```
echo "<select name=\"ativo\">";
while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) { echo "";

echo "<option value=";
echo $reg["tipo_info_questionario"];
echo "\"\> String de descricao</option>";
} `'
echo "</select>";
```

Sendo que além do valor vindo do value, cada option deve conter uma String para sua descrição (pode ser a mesma).

Até mais

Comment: Corrigido @Bacco, eu tinha copiado o código informado pelo usuário e não me toquei, o obrigado

Comment: continua com um echo vazio desnecessário, e com uns caracteres sobrando depois do `}`. Depois removo este comentário.

Answer (score 5):

Essa seria a forma correta de fazer o `while` para preencher seu `select`

```
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM pv_tipo_info_questionario");

echo "<select name='ativo'>";
while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) {
  echo "<option value='".$reg["cod_tipo_info"]."'>".$reg["tipo_info_questionario"]."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Este código deve apresentar algo semelhante a isso

```
<select name='ativo'>
   <option value='1'>Exemplo</option>
   <option value='2'>Exemplo</option>
   <option value='3'>Exemplo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Obrigado Diego Vieira e aos demais.

Answer (score 4):

Uma opção, que particularmente gosto de usar, separando o máximo possível o **PHP** do **HTML**:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "senha","bancodedados" ) or die (mysql_error());
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM pv_tipo_info_questionario");
?>
<select name="ativo">
    <?php while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) { ?>
    <option value="<?=$reg["cod_tipo_info"]?>"> <?=$reg["tipo_info_questionario"]?> </option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

OBS: Note que fazer `<?=$reg["cod_tipo_info"]?>` é o mesmo que `<?php echo $reg["cod_tipo_info"];?>`, para mais informações veja [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). Se você não tem a opção de short tags habilitada no servidor ou prefere não utilizar, você pode fazer:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "senha","bancodedados" ) or die (mysql_error());
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM pv_tipo_info_questionario");
?>
<select name="ativo">
    <?php while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $reg["cod_tipo_info"]?>"> <?php echo $reg["tipo_info_questionario"]?> </option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: Ótimas observações para iniciantes @abfurlan

Comment: @abfurlan.
Não esta aparecendo o botão.
Poderia ser por ter separado o código php?

Comment: @fabricio_wm qual botão? Neste código não existe botão :|

Comment: @fabricio_wm depois da tag `</select>` tem de abrir de novo a tag do PHP `<?php`

Comment: Mas eu abri. Estou pelo celular, agora. Assim q possivel, eu passo o codigo aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Olha Fabricio esse é o código para encher o teu `select` com os dados duma tabela retornados via MySQL e PHP.

```
<select name="ativo">
 <option> <?php echo "--Seleciona o tipo_info_questionario---" ?></option>         
    <?php 
   //Chamar a tua conexao
    $result= mysql_query("select * from pv_tipo_info_questionario");
      echo "<pre>";
          while($lista = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          print_r($lista);
      echo "<option value='{$lista['cod_tipo_info']}'>{$lista['tipo_info_questionario']}</option>";

    }
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>
</select>
```

NOTA: Podes gravar este código na extensão PHP e depois chamar no HTML.
Exemplo do nome: `SelectAtivo.php`

Para Chamar no HTML seria da seguinte maneira.
Exemplo Chamar:

```
<label>ATIVO:</label> <?php require_once 'SelectAtivo.php';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso esteja usando o class de PHP com Mysql assim funciona

```
    <label for="" id="Cidade">CIDADE:  </label>
    <select name="ComboboxCidade" size="1" id="ComboboxCidade">
         <?php  
        $cidades = CidadeDao::listaCidade();
        if($cidades <> null){   
            foreach ($cidades   as $key => $row) {
                echo "<option value=";
                echo $row ->getIdCidade();
                echo "\"\>";
                echo $row ->getNome();
                echo "</option>";
            }
        }
        ?>
```