# Mostrar informações do DB através do combobox

Tags: php, mysql

Estou uns dias procurando na internet e não sei se estou procurando de uma maneira errada só sei que não estou conseguindo achar o que preciso.

Seguinte: Eu gostaria de ao clicar em uma das opções que esta na ComboBox(ou menu/list), que me mostrasse o resultado logo abaixo.

Exemplo: tenho uma ComboBox com prioridade "Alta", "Média", "Baixa" e "Todos". Assim que eu clicar em uma dessas opções abaixo me mostra imediatamente os resultados de acordo com o que cliquei e que se encontra cadastrada no Mysql.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Estou usando a linguagem PHP apenas, mas caso necessite de javascript se puder me explicar como aplicar vou agradecer muito.

OBS: Eu não quero pegar os dados que esta no Mysql e por no Select. Eu quero é que ao clicar em uma das opções que já esta no select eu visualize abaixo o que esta no Mysql.

Coloquei essa "OBS" porque o que eu só achei ate agora foi como preencher o combobox sendo que quero é o contrario.

Comment: Acho que [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32357/91) e [esta outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23118/91) resposta podem ajudar a resolver o seu problema. Aproveite e veja  como site funciona na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

```
//Funções utilizadas

function conectar_banco_mysql(){
    $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=seu_bd";
    $username = "root";
    $passwd = "";
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd);
    return $pdo;    
}

function listarCategorias($tabela) {
    $pdo = conectar_banco_mysql();
    $listar = $pdo->query("select distinct categoria from $tabela ORDER BY categoria ASC ");
    $dados_encontrados = $listar->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
    return $dados_encontrados;
}


<form method="post" action="">
                <h3>Busca</h3>
                <h4>Categorias</h4>
                <input  type="hidden" name="local" value="" />
                <select class="input1" type="text" size="7" style="width:600px; background-color: #fff; color:#000; padding-left: 15px;" name="categoria" >
                    <?php
                    $categorias_encontradas = listarCategoria("nome_sua_tabela");
                    if (!empty($categorias_encontradas)):
                        foreach ($categorias_encontradas as $local):
                            // print_r($local);
                            ?>                          
                            <option value="<?php echo $local->categoria ?>"><?php echo $local->categoria ?>    
                                <?php
                            endforeach;
                        else:
                            ?>
                            Nenhuma entrada para processar!
                        <?php
                        endif;
                        ?>
                </select><br><br>

                <div class="botonstop">
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="pesquisar">
                </div>
            </form>       
            <?php
            @$busca = filter_var($_POST['categoria'], FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
// print_r($busca);
            if (!empty($_POST['categoria'])): //para obter o nome da categoria           
                $tarefas_encontradas = listarBusca('sua_tabela', $busca);
                foreach ($tarefas_encontradas as $caixa):
                    //  print_r($caixa);
                    ?> 
<!--Exemplo do relatório-->
                    <div class="post">                    
                        Tarefa n&#186  <?php echo $caixa->id_coluna_tabela; ?> |                     
                        Projeto n&#186 <?php echo $caixa->num_projeto_coluna_tabela; ?><br>
                        Data agendada: <?php echo $caixa->data_alvo_coluna_tabela; ?><br>
                        Última atualização:  <?php echo $caixa->data_coluna_tabela; ?><br>
                        <div>Categoria: <?php echo $caixa->categoria_coluna_tabela; ?></div><br>
                        Resumo: 
                        <div class="descrresum"><?php echo $caixa->titulo_resumido_coluna_tabela; ?></div><br>
                        Descrição:
                        <div  class="descrdescr"><?php echo $caixa->hist_coluna_tabela; ?></div><br>                        
                        <div class="botons">
                        <input class="btn btn-mini btn-info" type="button" VALUE="► Editar" onclick="location.href = '?p=actplan_alter&id=<?php echo $caixa->id; ?>';">
               <?php
                endforeach;
                ?>
                <?php
            else:
                echo '<h3 style="color: orange;">Nenhuma categoria selecionada!</h3> <h6 style="color:red;">Selecione <span style="color: black;">CLASSIFICAR</span> para ver tarefas sem categoria';
            endif;
            ?>
```